# Calling the same Viewcontroller file from within the file itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subview

The following segment of code opens a new page "ScreenA" with a animation motion:

```
                            ScreenA *Acca = [ScreenA alloc];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
        forView:self.view cache:YES]; 
[self.view addSubview:Acca.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It works fine but what if the call is to the page itself, meaning the file is ScreenA and I am calling the file to open again with different values to variables imbedded in the code of the file. When a call is made to a page even if it is to itself is all the memory released or is there a potential for a rescursive call that takes place building a stack of pages that will eventually crash the phone?

Really appreciate any help you might give me.

Thanks

Comment: Considering that only the first line of code is your own code, this is **really really bad code**. Instance names should be lowercase and you don't initialize ScreenA, you only alloc the memory. Learn to program in Obj-C, first!

Comment: That is what I call real positive input!

Answer (score 0):

I am just showing a code snippet to ask the bigger question about a screen calling itself. Please reconsider for an answer.